# iOS Enterprise Distrubution App from PHP Server

Tags: php, ios, enterprise-distribution

I am trying to allow some users to download the iOS app from my website (outside apple) for testing. For this i uploaded the plist and ipa file in  the folder, and had given, the link as follows on the page:

```
    <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://domain_name/test_1/Info.plist">
        link
    </a>
```

but it is not doing anything. nor showing download or any error message. i checked some of the links, 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18562
which has given me confusion, whether it can be done or not.

Do i also need to make changes in the plist files for this.

Please help.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an SSL certificate installed on your website, so it needs to be https. *(The above mentioned is https but you might have copied it?)*

When exporting, Xcode generates these files for you, make sure every url is https.